# When Drawing lines with VBO, how do I specify indices?

Tags: opengl, lines, indices

Was having trouble with drawing a list of lines. Do indices play a role? If They do, what would their ordering be in the indices buffer?

I could not find a reliable example online.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they definitely play a role. Say I wish to draw the following 5 lines:

```
0---1
|\  |
| \ |
|  \|
2---3
```

For `GL_LINES` each pair of indices specifies the first and the last point. The content of the indices buffer would be:

```
0 1 1 3 3 2 2 0 0 3
```

For `GL_LINE_STRIP` I specify the vertices in order I want to join with the lines. The content of the indices buffer would be:

```
0 1 3 2 0 3
```